# Create an object from a json value

Tags: python, arrays, json, object, iteration

I have a json file (estate.json) that looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "724543e2-bd9d-4bef-b9d6-a3ae73d330b7",
      "properties": {
        "objektidentitet": "724543e2-bd9d-4bef-b9d6-a3ae73d330b7",
        "adressplatsattribut": {
          "adressplatstyp": "Gatuadressplats",
          "insamlingslage": "Infart"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "1209dd85-d454-46be-bf9c-f2472095fcdc",
      "properties": {
        "objektidentitet": "1209dd85-d454-46be-bf9c-f2472095fcdc",
        "adressplatsattribut": {
          "adressplatstyp": "Gatuadressplats",
          "insamlingslage": "Byggnad"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "e12ee844-c138-4f21-95cc-9254e78721d0",
      "properties": {
        "objektidentitet": "e12ee844-c138-4f21-95cc-9254e78721d0",
        "adressplatsattribut": {
          "adressplatstyp": "Gatuadressplats",
          "insamlingslage": "Infart"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With the following lines:

```
f = open('estate.json')
d = json.load(f)

for id in d['features']:
    print(id['id'])
```

I can print the values from the keys 'objektidentitet' as:

```
724543e2-bd9d-4bef-b9d6-a3ae73d330b7
1209dd85-d454-46be-bf9c-f2472095fcdc
e12ee844-c138-4f21-95cc-9254e78721d0
```

I need to use these values in the upcoming step.
I believe that I need to create objects or variables for them?

I have tried creating classes (but I cant seem to understand them):

```
class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(k, (list, tuple)):
                setattr(self, k, [obj(x) if isinstance(x, dict) else x for x in v])
            else:
                setattr(self, k, obj(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v)
```

I have tried using recordclass and

```
def dict_to_class(class_name: Any, dictionary: dict) -> Any:
    instance = class_name()
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        setattr(instance, key, dictionary[key])
    return instance
```

Comment: `isinstance(k` should be `isinstance(v`

Comment: The first step you should take is to step through the code using a debugger. Then you can inspect the variables and see what they are, which should help you notice things like what Barmar pointed out; using keys where you meant values, etc. It will also allow you to see that the parsed json (into `d`) already includes the full navigatable tree of lists, dictionaries, etc, so should not need further transformation.

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert everything to `obj` class? I don't see the point of this class, since the attributes are just copies of the dictionary keys. Why not just keep it in the dictionaries and lists that `json.load()` returned?

Comment: I can't understand the question, because it appears that you have a fundamentally wrong idea of **what "object" means**, but I can't figure out exactly what your thought process is. To be clear: **everything that you assign to a variable in Python** is "an object".

Comment: A class whose attributes are entirely dynamic is not usually very useful.

Comment: "I need to use these values in the upcoming step." **What is** "the upcoming step?  Where you say "I believe that I need to create objects or variables for them?", exactly what do you think this means, and why do you think you need to do anything in particular at all? "I am sorry if I cannot explain this correctly" - well, *that is why you cannot find anything when you try to search for it*: you have no idea what to search for, because you don't understand what the words mean. The way to resolve this issue is to *abandon the current project and learn the language properly, from the start*.

Comment: If you can access the `id` values and print them, then it seems like you have everything you need.  I don't understand what else you are lacking in order to "use" the values...

Comment: You don't need to create anything. `d['features']` is a list of dicts. You can use those  dicts directly. If you *want* a class whose instances should be initialized using the data in the dicts, I would define the class and its `__init__` method first, then add a class method that uses the dict to construct an appropriate instance.

Answer (score -1):

> I need to use these values in the upcoming step. I believe that I
> need to create objects or variables for them? I have no idea where to
> start, I have been googling this for three months and nothing seem to
> match my dilemma?

Consider just tossing those values in a list, if you want to keep them separate from the json object:

```
d = json.loads('''{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "724543e2-bd9d-4bef-b9d6-a3ae73d330b7",
      "properties": {
        "objektidentitet": "724543e2-bd9d-4bef-b9d6-a3ae73d330b7",
        "adressplatsattribut": {
          "adressplatstyp": "Gatuadressplats",
          "insamlingslage": "Infart"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "1209dd85-d454-46be-bf9c-f2472095fcdc",
      "properties": {
        "objektidentitet": "1209dd85-d454-46be-bf9c-f2472095fcdc",
        "adressplatsattribut": {
          "adressplatstyp": "Gatuadressplats",
          "insamlingslage": "Byggnad"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "e12ee844-c138-4f21-95cc-9254e78721d0",
      "properties": {
        "objektidentitet": "e12ee844-c138-4f21-95cc-9254e78721d0",
        "adressplatsattribut": {
          "adressplatstyp": "Gatuadressplats",
          "insamlingslage": "Infart"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}''')

list_of_ids = [feature['id'] for feature in d['features']]
print(list_of_ids)
```

---

```
['724543e2-bd9d-4bef-b9d6-a3ae73d330b7', '1209dd85-d454-46be-bf9c-f2472095fcdc', 'e12ee844-c138-4f21-95cc-9254e78721d0']
```

Really though, do you need to put them in this separate list variable, when they are already easily accessible inside your json object `d`?

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to use classes, that would look like this, but it is very unncessary for actually *parsing JSON*. A dictionary returned by `json.load` is *already* a Python object.

```
class FeatureCollection:
  def __init__(self, features):
    self.features = features

class Feature:
  def __init__(self, _id, properties):
    self._id = _id
    self.properties = properties

features = []
with open('estate.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    for x in d['features']:
        features.append(Feature(x['id'], x['properties']))
fc = FeatureCollection(features)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to convert json to object in this case but it is a satisfying way to work with jsons (and dictionary) like an object (like in javascript).

in your case the answer is quite simple:

```py
d = json.loads("...")  # or json.load(open("path to json file"))
ids = [i['id'] for i in d['features']]
```

now `ids` is:

```py
['724543e2-bd9d-4bef-b9d6-a3ae73d330b7', '1209dd85-d454-46be-bf9c-f2472095fcdc', 'e12ee844-c138-4f21-95cc-9254e78721d0']
```

#### converting json to object-like instance

If we have a nested dictionary like below or that one in the question

```json
{
  "a": "a simple string",
  "b": {
    "a": "nested string",
    "b": {
      "c": [
        [
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
        ],
        {"a": "test1", "b": "test2", "c": {"d": 1}},
      ]
    },
  },
}
```

in python you should write this code:

```py
d = json.load(...)
d["b"]["b"]["c"][1]["c"]["d"] # -> 1
```

but it is more fun to just write:

```py
d = jsonobj(json.load(...))
d.b.b.c[1].c.d # -> 1
```

so the code that I wrote for converting a json to object, is here:

```py
class jsonobj:
    def __init__(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, jsonobj.nested_convert(v))

    @classmethod
    def nested_convert(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return jsonobj(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            return [jsonobj.nested_convert(i) for i in v]
        else:
            return v
```

My code aimed to convert json to object but a dictionary in python could be more complex.